# How can I get all model estimates automatically in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lme4, predict

I know I can calculate models' estimates by hand, but **I'm sure there's a way to get all model estimates for all categorical levels automatically**. Since I'm dealing with `lmers`, maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174203/predict-function-for-lmer-mixed-effects-models) should be suitable. Note: I **don't** want to predict new data, I just wanna get all estimates automatically. (just edited the post to make it easier to understand)

- an example:

```
> model <- lmer(Score ~ Proficiency_c * testType + (1|ID), data = myData, REML = F)

> summary(model)

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   4.8376     0.2803 156.9206  17.259  < 2e-16 ***
Proficiency_c                -1.3381     0.4405 156.9206  -3.038  0.00279 ** 
testTypeTestB                 0.2088     0.3269 126.0000   0.639  0.52421    
testTypeTestC                 0.4638     0.3269 126.0000   1.418  0.15853    
Proficiency_c:testTypeTestB   0.5008     0.5138 126.0000   0.975  0.33157    
Proficiency_c:testTypeTestC   0.2357     0.5138 126.0000   0.459  0.64727  
---

> contrasts(myData$testType)

      TestB TestC
TestA     0     0
TestB     1     0
TestC     0     1
```

- 'by hand', I would:

```
## estimate for Test A:

y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + b4(x1 * x2) + b5(x1 * x3)
y = b0 + b1 * 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
y = b0 + b1 
y = 3.49

## estimate for Test B:

y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + b4(x1 * x2) + b5(x1 * x3)
y = b0 + b1 * 1 + b2 * 1 + 0 +  b4(1 * 1) + 0
y = b0 + b2 + (b1 + b4)x1 
y = 4.20

## estimate for Test C:

y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + b4(x1 * x2) + b5(x1 * x3)
y = b0 + b1 * 1 + b2 * 0 + b3 * 1 + 0 + b5 (1 * 1)
y = b0 + b3 + (b1 + b5)x1 
y = 4.19
```

*edited question*

- I usually deal with people who don't know how to come up with the model's estimates by themselves, so I usually have to calculate them all 'by hand'. I just wish there was a way to get all 'ys' estimates concerning each categorical level (as I did 'by hand' above) without doing that manually? Again, for now, I don't want to predict new values. Thanks in advance!
- data:

```
 dput(myData)
structure(list(ID = c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p3", 
"p3", "p3", "p4", "p4", "p4", "p5", "p5", "p5", "p6", "p6", "p6", 
"p7", "p7", "p7", "p8", "p8", "p8", "p9", "p9", "p9", "p10", 
"p10", "p10", "p11", "p11", "p11", "p12", "p12", "p12", "p13", 
"p13", "p13", "p14", "p14", "p14", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p16", 
"p16", "p16", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p18", "p18", "p18", "p19", 
"p19", "p19", "p20", "p20", "p20", "p21", "p21", "p21", "p22", 
"p22", "p22", "p23", "p23", "p23", "p24", "p24", "p24", "p25", 
"p25", "p25", "p26", "p26", "p26", "p27", "p27", "p27", "p28", 
"p28", "p28", "p29", "p29", "p29", "p30", "p30", "p30", "p31", 
"p31", "p31", "p32", "p32", "p32", "p33", "p33", "p33", "p34", 
"p34", "p34", "p35", "p35", "p35", "p36", "p36", "p36", "p37", 
"p37", "p37", "p38", "p38", "p38", "p39", "p39", "p39", "p40", 
"p40", "p40", "p41", "p41", "p41", "p42", "p42", "p42", "p43", 
"p43", "p43", "p44", "p44", "p44", "p45", "p45", "p45", "p46", 
"p46", "p46", "p47", "p47", "p47", "p48", "p48", "p48", "p49", 
"p49", "p49", "p50", "p50", "p50", "p51", "p51", "p51", "p52", 
"p52", "p52", "p53", "p53", "p53", "p54", "p54", "p54", "p55", 
"p55", "p55", "p56", "p56", "p56", "p57", "p57", "p57", "p58", 
"p58", "p58", "p59", "p59", "p59", "p60", "p60", "p60", "p61", 
"p61", "p61", "p62", "p62", "p62", "p63", "p63", "p63"), Score = c(5.33, 
5.05, 5.15, 5.82, 2.29, 7.54, 4.46, 2.43, 1.53, 8.97, 7.69, 7.21, 
6.76, 8.41, 3.77, 3.33, 11.57, 7.69, 2.15, 3.84, 3.29, 3.36, 
6.66, 5.6, 4.23, 4.41, 3.07, 2.29, 4.9, 4.46, 3.22, 1.72, 2.08, 
4.47, 2.4, 2.54, 2.73, 6.57, 7.31, 4.46, 9.27, 4.31, 4.54, 6.32, 
8.97, 3.44, 4.68, 9.7, 2.15, 5.68, 5.26, 9.3, 5.68, 8.97, 4.65, 
4.13, 4.57, 11.22, 11.39, 7.52, 3.94, 4.47, 3.52, 5, 8, 5.81, 
2.96, 4.05, 2.22, 4.41, 5.64, 4.79, 2.43, 2.5, 4.16, 7.57, 9.21, 
2.59, 3.12, 3.84, 7.76, 8.77, 5.08, 7.81, 4.49, 2.17, 7.4, 5.81, 
4.9, 3.19, 3.2, 2.72, 3.67, 4.42, 3.57, 1.02, 4.42, 2.45, 5.88, 
7.84, 4.93, 9.61, 3.75, 1.8, 3.47, 0.65, 1.39, 2.9, 6.36, 2.77, 
2.67, 6.89, 6.74, 6.81, 1.94, 3.22, 3.12, 4.08, 5.31, 11.23, 
4.1, 4.28, 3.89, 2.98, 3.52, 3.64, 3.63, 5.08, 4.9, 6.66, 7.56, 
3.14, 5.26, 1.03, 4.58, 2.9, 2.5, 3.57, 4, 7.54, 3.5, 5.19, 2.56, 
2.38, 1.4, 3.97, 2, 8.69, 5.33, 6.42, 3.62, 2.59, 4.63, 4.85, 
6.87, 5.55, 3.14, 2.29, 4.68, 7.76, 3.53, 8.88, 3.44, 8, 5.15, 
6.77, 12.28, 6.25, 4.91, 7.01, 7.4, 5.21, 3, 4.87, 7.5, 5.47, 
8.97, 7.89, 7.54, 9.25, 7.24, 5.37, 6.41, 2.94, 5.47, 7.14, 5.4, 
5.06, 6.32), Proficiency_c = c(0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.69, 0.69, 
0.69, 1.24, 1.24, 1.24, -0.16, -0.16, -0.16, 1.14, 1.14, 1.14, 
0.69, 0.69, 0.69, -0.26, -0.26, -0.26, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, -0.26, 
-0.26, -0.26, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, -0.06, -0.06, 
-0.06, -0.41, -0.41, -0.41, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, 
-0.81, -0.81, -0.81, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, 0.44, 
0.44, 0.44, -0.11, -0.11, -0.11, -0.21, -0.21, -0.21, -0.51, 
-0.51, -0.51, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, -0.21, -0.21, 
-0.21, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -1.01, -1.01, 
-1.01, -0.26, -0.26, -0.26, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 
-0.11, -0.11, -0.11, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.79, 
0.79, 0.79, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, -0.76, -0.76, -0.76, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -0.11, -0.11, -0.11, -0.61, -0.61, -0.61, 
0.19, 0.19, 0.19, -0.36, -0.36, -0.36, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -1.01, 
-1.01, -1.01, 1.19, 1.19, 1.19, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, 0.99, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.74, 0.74, 0.74, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, 
-0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, 
0.89, 0.89, 0.89, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -1.01, -1.01, -1.01, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.66, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.36, -0.36, -0.36), testType = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("TestA", 
"TestB", "TestC"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -189L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: *"I don't want to predict new data, I just wanna get all estimates automatically... Again, for now, I don't want to predict new values."*. The only ~~nice~~ programmtic way I know to calculate estimates like this is to set up dummy data and predict on it. You seem **very sure** that's not what you want to do... so I'll move along.

Comment: And is there a reason you're leaving `b0` in your calculations? If you're looking for the impact of a 1-unit change, you should be calculating `y2 - y1`, and the intercept goes away, and you're left with the `Proficiency_c` coef, `-1.338`. As you say, a 1-unit change should be `b1`, but you have `b0 + b1`.

Comment: hi! @GregorThomas , so, first comment: I always interpret models to my friends 'by hand' doing the calculations, I'd like to have a way to simple generate them automatically. This is a simple one, but we may have more complex ones and I'd like to 'automatize' the process as well as to have a way to 'check' that the by hand calculations are correct. Second comment: no special reason, I just left the whole equation there to get the estimates

Comment: Especially with more complicated equations, I can't think of a more concise way to specify exactly what estimates you want other than other than generating fake data and predicting on it. That's very exact, and you know just what you get. I'll watch with interest in case you find the other way you're sure exists, but I sure haven't seen it.

Comment: (As for the intercept, I'm not asking why your equation included the intercept, I'm asking why your result did: it seems wrong. You show: `1-unit change in 'Proficiency' for Test A = b0 + b1 = 3.49`. I think it should be `1-unit change in 'Proficiency' for Test A = b1 = -1.34`. But I want to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, so I'm checking to see if you agree it's a mistake or if you can help explain what I'm missing.)

Comment: Hi, @GregorThomas , forget the intercept. I edited the post, hopefully it's clearer now what I need. I usually deal with people who don't know how to come up with the model's estimations by themselves (aka, they don't know how to look at model's betas and calculate as I did above), so I always have to interpret all models 'by hand' to them. I just wanted a 'shortcut', is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, I get what you want. I and everyone else I know get the results you want  by making fake data, running `predict` on it, and taking some differences. But in your question you insist that you *"don't want to predict new values"*. I don't really understand why you don't want to do it that way. I don't know of any "automatic" shortcuts. I'm doubtful there are any as I think the general problem is quite difficult--you've got a relatively simple case, but if one were to code up a general solution I think it would be very difficult to detect programmatically what is needed.

Comment: For example, I'm making a report now on the data I've posted above and, indeed, there are 8 models in total. One part of the report goes like this and  I'm calculating 'by hand' every single estimate in the report as "estimate for test A is 3.49 (b0), for test B is 4.20 (b0 + b2 + b1 + b4) and for test C is 4.19 (b0 + b3 + b1 + b5)" . I just wish there's a way to optimize the process... I need to make the person understand the 'basic' estimates for her data (tho it'll be the mean for categorical data) before generalizing them to new data

Comment: btw, what do you mean by 'and taking some differences' after using ```predict``` ?

Comment: I mean something like this: if I want to know the modeled difference between `testType = "B"` and `testType = "C"`, I'd create `pred_data = data.frame(testType =c("B", "C"))` with, say, mean values the other columns like `Proficiency_c`, then run `predict()` on that new prediction data, and then calculate the difference in the predictions. For one difference like this it's cumbersome, but you can use `expand.grid` to generate all combinations of predictors you're interested in. But seeing Ben Bolker's answer it looks like I'm happily wrong about there not being a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're calculating predictions at a reference proficiency of 1 (0 would be the default), but maybe you're looking for `emmeans`?

```r
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model, ~testType, at = list(Proficiency_c=1))
```

The `at =`  argument is the way to specify in `emmeans` that we want to calculate marginal means with the non-focal parameters (`Proficiency_c` in this case) set to a value other than the default [typically the mean of a numeric covariate]. See `vignette("basics", package = "emmeans")` (`emmeans` has many high-quality vignettes). It's specified as a list because we may have multiple non-focal parameters to set.

Results:

```
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 testType emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 TestA      3.50 0.529 162     2.45     4.54
 TestB      4.21 0.529 162     3.16     5.25
 TestC      4.20 0.529 162     3.15     5.24

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

If you're looking for the estimated *slope* within each test type, use `emtrends`:

```r
emtrends(model, ~testType, "Proficiency_c")
 testType Proficiency_c.trend    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 TestA                 -1.338 0.448 162    -2.22  -0.4541
 TestB                 -0.837 0.448 162    -1.72   0.0467
 TestC                 -1.102 0.448 162    -1.99  -0.2185

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Hi, @Ben Bolker, thanks! Indeed, I wasn't looking at *proficiency = 1*, I see that I was a bit confusing in the original post... Thank you, that was what I was looking for!

Comment: The only reason I included `proficiency = 1` in my answer is that it matched the computations you showed in your question (and the answers, up to rounding).

Comment: yeah, I got it, I recognize I was confusing in the post... Thank you! It was indeed what I was looking for!

Comment: could you tell me, tho, why should we include ```proficiency_c``` as  a `list' ?